# Where to change the font color for the annoatations in phpstorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm, setting

PhpStorm offers the feature to show annotations of a file via `Annotate`.

I wanted to change to color as I am using a dark theme and the currently used dark blue is very hard to read since contrast is lacking.

[image: phpstorm annotation with hard to read font]

I was looking through the settings yet did not find the place to change it.

Where to set the annotation font color?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]
Prefences and go to the
General VCS Annotations

Comment: Thank you for saving my headache.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a user of PHPStorm but I guess IntelliJ IDEA works the same. Go to Preferences->Editor->Color&Fonts->General and the look for VCS annotations:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Preferences]